# Nested replies in a comment sections - How to add new replies for Firebase Firestore

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Right now, to add a reply I have to do this:

```
final CollectionReference postsRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance
  .collection('Media')
  .doc("<docNumber>")
  .collection("Posts")
  .doc(document)
  .collection("Replies");
```

I want there to be a way that I could dynamically add replies collection to a document. Right now, the only way for me to do that is if I do `.doc().col().doc().col().doc().col()...` etc.

As you see, I would rather only have to give a single path instead of having to add many nested collections for adding the information. Is there a way I can just provide a string path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can provide a path like this:

```
final CollectionReference postsRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance
  .collection('Media/${docID}/Posts/${docID2}/Replies')
```

A `CollectionReference` has **odd** and a `DocumentReference` has **even** number of path segments. So if you want to point to a document, it'll be:

```
.doc('Media/${docID}/Posts/${docID2}/Replies/${docID3}')
```